# Write in an HTML input field using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, getelementsbytagname, input-field

I load an internet page and log in with `myusername` and `mypassword` using VBA.

I would like to write a search-term in an input field of the webpage using VBA.

Because there is no name and ID in the input field, I didn't succeed.

Here is my code :

```
Sub MyLogin()

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://www.example.com"

    Do Until .readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    .document.all.Item("username").Value = "myusername"
    .document.all.Item("password").Value = "mypassword"
    .document.forms(0).submit

End With

Do Until IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Dim inputfield As HTMLInputElement
For Each inputfield In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If inputfield.Type = "text" Then inputfield.Value = "mysearch"
Next

Do Until IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

End Sub
```

The HTML field I want to fill:

> input class="input-inboxsearch form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="Nom, email" maxlength="71"

How can I set the value of the input field?

Comment: Try using `getElementsByClassName ("input-inboxsearch form-control")` instead,

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Miqi180's comment, you can try replacing your the section of your code starting with `Dim inputfield As HTMLInputElement` with this:

```
Dim inputfield As Object
Set inputfield = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("input-inboxsearch form-control")
If inputfield.length > 0 Then
    inputfield(0).Value = "mysearch"
End If

'carry on with your code
```

The `getElementsByClassName` method will return a collection so you have to check its `length` and then access the items of the collection. If there is only one element with that class then you can reference the 0th element of the collection.

I've set the `inputfield` variable as an `Object` because you appear to be using late binding.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did the modifications. There is no error message. However nothing appear un the search field.

Comment: When I debug.print inputfield.length, it returns 0.  Is there something which can prevent the getelementsbyclass process to collect data? When I try the process on a google webpage, it works perfectly fine. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Maybe you need to double-check the class attribute on the input field - are you sure it is `input-inboxsearch form-control` ? Normally, this should just work - I note that your code already has navigated to a page and then logged in. Maybe you need to check that `IE.document` refers to your second page (after log-in) not the first (pre log-in).

Comment: Many thanks for your assist. The class attribute is correct. I think there is a conflict between the 2 webpages as you said (pre log-in and after log-in). Should I rename the second webpage ? Any advise on how to do it would be very appreciated. The help provided so far has been extremely useful. Thanks to the contributers.